# Почему не показывается за какие именно ответы потеряны голоса удалённого участника?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация, удаление-профиля

Периодически прилетает уведомление "Участник был удалён", сопровождающееся потерей некоторого количества репутации. Но если источник начисления репутации всегда виден, то места потерь нет. Разработчики специально так сделали, потому что такая механика чем-то лучше? Если да, то чем? Или у этого есть техническое обоснование, вроде "вместе с учётной записью удаляется информация о голосах"? Или это просто недоработка?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как обнаружил [@Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) на Meta.SE ([How can I find posts related to lost reputation due to a “user was removed” message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126698/how-can-i-find-posts-related-to-lost-reputation-due-to-a-user-was-removed-mess)) затронутые посты скрываются только на уровне интерфейса сайта и доступны через мобильное приложение Stack Exchange и  Stack Exchange API.

Список затронутых постов можно получить так:

- перейти на [страницу документации API по изменениям репутации](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-full-reputation-history#filter=default&site=ru.stackoverflow&run=true);
- нажать на кнопку «Get Token» и авторизоваться;
- нажать на кнопку «Run».

В полученном JSON искать события по которым `reputation_history_type = user_deleted`:

```
{
  "reputation_history_type": "user_deleted",
  "reputation_change": -10,
  "post_id": 985230,
  "creation_date": 1559045442,
  "user_id": 178556
},
```

По `post_id` перейти к затронутому вопросу.

При желании это дело можно автоматизировать.

### Причина сокрытия информации

Насколько я понял, раньше откат репутации отображался детально везде. С определенного момента его без объяснений скрыли на сайте.

Некоторые авторитетные участники Meta.SE утверждают, что это связано с анонимностью голосования удаленных участников ([Why is it not possible to have more information about “User was removed”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155876/why-is-it-not-possible-to-have-more-information-about-user-was-removed)):

> *On which questions did you lose reputation:*
>
> Giving out that information would compromise the anonymity of votes, **if you know who was deleted (which is often easy to find out, at least for high-reputation users), you know how they voted on your posts.**

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл такой вопрос: [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/260198).

> As a result, all of their votes were removed, and the reputation you
>   gained or lost from them was undone. The resultant reputation change
>   could be any amount; it could even be a reputation gain if enough of
>   the removed votes were downvotes. All the removed events are rolled
>   into one, so **there is no way for you to find each affected post**

Comment: А вот зачем "removed events are rolled into one"?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev пока не нашёл ответа. Я подобное мог бы объяснить со своей колокольни. Но хотелось бы, конечно, ответа именно от команды SE.